Como hacer una barra con tres partes con bordes redondeados
Quiero hacer una gráfica como la siguiente:

he hecho el siguiente código:
# Datos
partes = [100, 100, 55]
colores = ['#B7E3F6', '#A1C9DB', '#79B1C8']
nombres = [str(p) for p in partes]  # Convertir los números en cadenas

# Crear el gráfico de barras con esquinas redondeadas
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2))
plt.barh(0, partes[0], color=colores[0], height=0.5, capstyle='round')
plt.barh(0, partes[1], left=partes[0], color=colores[1], height=0.5, capstyle='round')
plt.barh(0, partes[2], left=partes[0] + partes[1], color=colores[2], height=0.5, capstyle='round')

# Agregar los números encima de cada parte
for i in range(len(partes)):
    plt.text(sum(partes[:i]) + partes[i] / 2, 0, nombres[i], ha='center', va='center', color='black')

# Quitar ejes
plt.axis('off')

# Mostrar el gráfico
plt.show()

pero me sale lo siguiente:

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

No parece fácil https://stackoverflow.com/q/61568935/13419694

En lugar de dibujar barras, puedes optar por usar líneas gruesas. Estas líneas pueden presentar bordes redondeados. Si las dibujas en orden inverso, conseguirás que la línea de la izquierda quede en la parte superior.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Datos
partes = [100, 100, 55]
colores = ['#B7E3F6', '#A1C9DB', '#79B1C8']
nombres = [str(p) for p in partes]  # Convertir los números en cadenas

# Crear el gráfico de barras con esquinas redondeadas
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2))
for i in range(len(partes))[::-1]:
    plt.plot([sum(partes[:i]), sum(partes[:i + 1])], [0, 0],
             color=colores[i], lw=30, solid_capstyle='round')

# Agregar los números encima de cada parte
for i in range(len(partes)):
    plt.text(sum(partes[:i]) + partes[i] / 2, 0, nombres[i], ha='center', va='center', color='black')

# Quitar ejes
plt.axis('off')

# Mostrar el gráfico
plt.show()


